# Docker-Compose asking for gcloud credentials

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I run my docker-compose.yml file I always get the following error message:

```
docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-gcloud not installed or not available in PATH
```

I found a lot of solutions for people that want to use the gcloud credentials. I don't want to use it and don't know why it's asking for that. I think it's a wrong configuration with docker-compose since I get everything up and running, if I build the containers individually with their Dockerfiles.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: './web'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  search:
    build: './search'
    ports:
      - "3001:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      - MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb://db/microservices

  books:
    build: './books'
    ports:
      - "3002:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      - MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb://db/microservices

  videos:
    build: './videos'
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      - MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb://db/microservices

  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./web/public:/srv/www/static
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - web
      - books
      - search
      - videos
```

Answer (score 13):

Try deleting `~/.docker/config.json`. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1401705/docker-gcloud-how-to-fix-docker-credential-gcloud-not-installed-or-not-avail) and [here](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/383).

Comment: Specifically I ripped out the `credHelpers` lines referencing gcloud, and that was sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

update your .docker/config.json in order to disable gcloud . and everything gonna work fine .

from this :

[image]

to this :

[image]

Have a nice ContainerING :-)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I have no idea why I was asked for the gcloud credentials but I uninstalled Docker-Desktop and reinstalled it and now it works just as intended.

Comment: Had the same issue ... Did the uninstall and reinstall thing and it worked for one day! Now it is back to comparing about gcloud credentials. :(